# How to grant permissions to single SELECT/UPDATE statment (sql server)?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a problem when trying to execute this update statement (below) using C# SqlCommand when I execute it locally it works fine, but when deployed to another machine I got a permission error

The SELECT permission was denied on the object Order ...
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object Order ...

Update Statement

```
UPDATE Order SET Request = @request WHERE Id = @ID;
```

Is there any way to add GRANT SELECT and GRANT UPDATE to a single statement like the update above without using a stored procedure?

or the SP is the way to go on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using sql authentication or windows authentication?  Sounds like windows authentication.  make sure that the user who is logged in on the other workstation has the correct rights granted.

Comment: this is a windows service and it is using sql authentication it actually uses some sp which have the GRANT  EXECUTE  ON SP_NAME TO USERS

Comment: however since I needed only to do that single update I didn't want to create an SP, however it does not work since it seems to need the GRANT permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedure is the way to go, then you can assign execute rights to that stored procedure without granting rights on the base table.  SQL Server cannot assign rights to individual ad hoc SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't grant permissions on statements. You can grant SELECT, you can grant UPDATE, but on the **table**, not on the particular statements.

The best solution is to use stored procedures indeed. Execute the allowed SELECT and the allowed UPDATE from a stored procedure and use code signing to grant the necessary permissions, see [Module Signing (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102.aspx). Using code signing is more granular and better constrained than the alternative: relying on procedure and table common ownership for execution permissions.

Comment: You can also GRANT at the column level, but again, SPs are a good solution here.